# maked proportion by cyclic angle

Tags: geometry

In the below shape we know CD and AP are perpendicular. prove that $\frac{PA}{PB}=\frac{QA}{QB}$

[image]

Comment: Who can prove this without using Sins.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so i will add point E as intersection of diameter AB and chord CD, and point F as intersection of OC and MD.

Since CD and AB are perpendicular,CE=ED and BD=CD.

Denote $\angle CAB = \alpha $ and $\angle DQB= \beta $.

Then $\angle CAB = \angle DAB = \angle CDB= \angle BDC = \alpha $ (Inscribed angles over the same or equal chord)

$\angle COB = 2 \angle CAB = 2 \alpha $ and because triangle AOC is isosceles , $ \angle BAC = \angle ACO = \alpha $

Since $\angle DQB= \angle OQF = \beta$, angle $\angle MFC= \angle OFQ= 180-(2\alpha+\beta)$

Then $\angle MDO= \beta$ and $  \angle MDA= \beta - \alpha$ and $ \angle BCP=180-90-(\beta - \alpha)= 90+\alpha - \beta$

Laq of sines on triangles QAC and QCB

$\frac{QA}{QC}= \frac{\sin(\beta-\alpha)}{\sin\alpha}$ and $\frac{QB}{QC}= \frac{\sin(90-\beta+\alpha)}{\sin(90-\alpha)}= \frac{\cos(\beta-\alpha)}{\cos \alpha} $ from that it follows that

$\frac{QA}{QB}=\frac{\tan(\beta-\alpha)}{\tan \alpha} $

Again law of sines on triangles PBD and PAD

$\frac{PA}{PD}= \frac{\sin(180-(\beta-\alpha))}{\sin \alpha}= \frac{\sin (\beta-\alpha)}{\sin \alpha}$ and

$ \frac{PB}{PD}= \frac{\sin(90-(\beta-\alpha))}{\sin(90+\alpha)}= \frac{\cos(\beta-\alpha)}{\cos \alpha} $

It follows that $ \frac{PA}{PB}= \frac{\tan(\beta-\alpha)}{\tan \alpha}$ so

$ \frac{PA}{PB}=\frac{QA}{QB}$

Comment: why OD and MC should have an intersection?

Comment: $\angle OQA = 0$ not $\beta$. where is G?

Comment: It seems that I mixed points C and D, I will edit it.

Comment: $\angle MDB$ is $\alpha + \beta$ and I think what you find for $\angle BDP$ is wrong

Comment: I forgot to change$ \angle BDP$ to $\angle BCP$ when I as editing. (Since I mixed those two points). We have $\angle DQB =\beta \Rightarrow QDC=90-\beta $, so $\angle MDB = \angle QDC + \angle CDB = 90 -\beta + \alpha $

Comment: but yet $\angle MDA$ is $\alpha+\beta$ not $\beta -\alpha$

Comment: $\angle ADB = 90 $ because it is inscribed angle over diameter AB. Then $\angle MDA = 90 - \angle MDB = 90 - (90-\beta + \alpha)=\beta - \alpha $. What picture are you looking at? In your previous comment you were claiming that $\angle MDB = \alpha+\beta$ and now that$ \angle MDA= \alpha + \beta$.

Comment: OK it was my mistake to say $\angle MDB$ and you did mistake when you write $\angle MDO=\beta$ because $\angle MDO$ is $\beta - 2\alpha$ and so $\angle MDA = \beta - \alpha$

Comment: Also I don't understand how you find $\angle BCP$. $\angle CPB= \beta - \alpha$ and $\angle PBC= 90+\alpha$ then $\angle BCP= 90- \beta$. However I understand your way to prove and don't continue more. I would liked this be proved without Sins low. thanks

Answer (score 1):

there should be a better geometric argument. my last resort is coordinate geometry.

choose the units so that the radius of the circle is $1.$ pick the coordinates so that $O$ the center of the circle is the origin and $B= (1,0), A = (-1,0), M= (\cos s, \sin s), D = (\cos t, -\sin t),C = (\cos t, \sin t).$  the equation of $MC$ is $$y(\cos s - \cos t) - x (\sin s - \sin t) = \sin (t-s).$$ the $x$-intercept $b$ is 
$$b = \dfrac{\sin(t-s)}{\sin t - \sin s},\,\dfrac{AP}{BP}=\dfrac{b+1}{b-1} = 
\dfrac{\sin(t-s) + \sin t - \sin s}{\sin(t-s) - \sin t + \sin s} = 
\dfrac{\cos t/2 \cos s/2}{\sin t/2 \sin s/2}$$

to find $\dfrac{AQ}{BQ}$ we replace $t$ by $-t$ and compute

$$\bar b = \dfrac{\sin(t+s)}{\sin t + \sin s},\,\dfrac{AQ}{BQ}=\dfrac{\bar b+1}{1- \bar b} = 
\dfrac{\sin(t+s) + \sin t + \sin s}{-\sin(t+s) + \sin t + \sin s} = 
\dfrac{\cos t/2 \cos s/2}{\sin t/2 \sin s/2}$$

so we have shown $$ \dfrac{AP}{BP} = \dfrac{AQ}{BQ}.$$

Comment: Why did you use the angle t for both M and D? I don't understand what is b?

Comment: that was a typo. i have fixed it now. $C$ and $D$ are images on the $x$-axis so they have opposite angle coordinates.

Comment: $b$ is the $x$-coordinate of $P.$  and $\bar b$ is the $x$-coordinate of $Q.$

Comment: How you find MC? what are x and y? I am unfamiliar with this kind of geometry

Comment: How you find MC? what are x and y? I am unfamiliar by this kind of geometry

Comment: you dont need to find $MC$ and i did not. i found the equation of line $MC$ so that i can get the $x$-intercept.